# Why Am I getting segmentation fault when my input exceeds 5?

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault

so i've done the Hours practice problem in week 2 butt I'm getting the segmentation fault whenever the number I input(1st prompt) exceeds 5.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int N = 0;

int total(int array[]);
float average(int array[]);

int main(void)
{
    // to prompt the me to input whatever week i'm in then loop a get_int to ask the hours i spent on each week
    int score[N];
    N = get_int("Number of weeks taking CS50: ");

    int hours = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        score[i] = get_int("Week %i hours: ", hours);
        hours++;
    }

// to prompt the me in picking if i want a totsl or avg

    char result;
    do
    {
        result = get_char("Enter T for total hours, A for average: ");
    }
    while (result != 'T' && result != 'A');

    if (result == 'T')
    {
        printf("%i hours\n", total(score));
    }
    else if (result == 'A')
    {
        printf("%f hours\n", average(score));
    }
}


// functions to compute what they said on their names

int total(int array[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[j];
    }
    return sum;
}

float average(int array[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++)
    {
```

Note: I'm using the cs50 vscode codespace for this. So far this is the only bug i've seen in this code so please let me know about your opinions and guidance. Be blatant as you can.

Comment: What's the value of `N` before the statement `N = get_int("Number of weeks taking CS50: ");`?

Comment: Given `int N = 0;`, how big do you think `int score[N];` is?

Answer (score 0):

you've set score to a zero-sized array using

```
int score[N];
```

and then you've changed N using

```
N = get_int("Number of weeks taking CS50: ");
```

score is still zero-sized array even after you've changed N.
You should use either:

if N can't be higher than 100, for example:

- int score[100];

or, the better approach, use after N is set:

- score = malloc(N*sizeof(int))

Comment: Where is `X` coming from? And dynamically allocating an array of zero size won't solve the problem.

Comment: @Chris just an example. Changed it to constant 100